Would a 'premature detonating' forcefield-type device be effective against shaped charge warheads?
As I've been thinking over how I might go about implementing forcefields into my setting, I considered the idea that 'early' shield designs might operate differently from the usual ability for shields to outright block incoming projectiles. These shields would, however, still offer a degree of resistance, and have the benefit over 'physical' armour of being self-regenerating and lighter.
Most of what I've come across on the topic of anti shaped charge defences such as slat or bar armour focuses ability to disable such a warhead's fuse without detonation, which I currently hadn't intended for these shields to be able to do, and some sources even suggest that premature detonation might even improve penetrative performance. Assuming that these shields would be projected out to a metre or so from the hull of the vehicle, would that offer enough distance between the warhead and the vehicle to prevent penetration?
The warheads in question can be assumed to be equivalent to late Cold War era models such as TOW.

Can you clarify what your forcefield actually does? Is it just creating a 1m standoff between the shaped charge and vehicle at the moment of detonation?

This question doesn't make a lot of sense. Prematurely detonating pretty much any missile other than a nuke would render the missile useless - and if you prematurely detonate a nuke far enough away, even it's useless. Magic always overcomes reality unless you define its characteristics otherwise. Do you want help balancing your magic system (aka, defining the characteristics of your force field to better balance the story/game play/world)? We're pretty good at that.

I'm curious where you've heard the disables-the-fuse-without-detonating idea. Every discussion of slat armor I've seen is specifically about detonating it early/at the wrong distance.

@Cadence That is not how slat armor actually works.  Modern HEAT rounds use electric contact detonators (because chemical detonators have major issues with deflection when they hit sloped armor). Slat armor only has about a 60% success rate against HEAT rounds, but when it works, it allows the contact fuse to pass between the slats, and then it crushes or slices the inner chamber before it can detonate.

Often times this will short circuit the trigger system effectively disabling the fuse, but more often, it just deforms the round before it detonates so that it explodes instead of making a jet.  When the fuse does make contact with the slats, the spaced effect might help a bit, but unless you're already in a main battle tank, it's unlikely to make enough difference to save you since the space is typically only a few cm.

Still no answer marked?

After a fashion its already been done - at least experimentally.
Boeing has apparently patented (but not put into production) a system that uses microwaves and/or lasers mounted on a military vehicle to generate a 'plasma shield' in front of approaching missiles. It's a very complicated set up but basically sensors detect an incoming round on a collision course, a computer calculates its trajectory and then the lasers/microwave emitters generate a brief plasma shield (ionized air) in front of the incoming round. The shock of impact causes HEAT and other explosive rounds to detonate prematurely but sabot/solid armor piercing rounds while they might be deflected (a little) would still pass through largely unaffected
[Boeing Force Field Article - Popular Mechanics][1]
[1]: https://www.popularmechanics.com/military/research/a14683/boeing-patent-plasma-shield/
P.S. From memory (and I could be wrong) I think BAE was working on another form of electromagnetic armor for fighting vehicles also designed to deal with HEAT rounds but you'd have to check if this is the kind of 'force field' effect your looking for.

Probably not. Here's why...
Typical armour piercing shells have an explosive head, with a hollow cone surrounded by high explosive. An explosive wave implodes the cone, turning it into a fast, thin jet of liquid metal. This can penetrate feet of old-school solid metal armour.
Modern has voids and variations in density which can break up the liquid metal jet into a spray. There should be a layer beneath this of weak material so the spray can spread out over a larger area, and lose some of its energy. It can then be resisted by conventional armour.
Can your 'force field' do this? Magnetic and electrical fields spread out and become more uniform. They might trigger the formation of the jet in the incoming shell, but these jets can travel several meters in air and still penetrate armour. I would imagine the jet could travel through the force field without being dispersed.
The wood on the Filipino tank may disperse a jet somewhat, but a plank of wood is still too uniform, and too close to the surface. If you want home-made armour, use plastic bottle crates as a spacer, topped with bags of BBQ charcoal (light option), or gravel (heavy, but probably more effective).
I used to work with explosives, and with home-made shields to stop the debris from experiments damaging the bomb chambers. That was the same sort of thing but inside-out, with the gap to the bomb chamber wall providing the spacer layer.

What shaped charge are you looking at that has it's jet extend out for meters? Shaped charges don't have that kind of range. Their usefulness is being able to punch through almost any kind of armor within the range of the jet, but they do not have unlimited reach: the best we have today makes a jet about 10 times the diameter of the warhead(7 times is more standard), which is typically 4-5 cm. Also bolting on wood to the Filipino tank actually did work against older warheads; that's why they did it.

There is a video by the Slo-Mo Guys where they do a slow-motion shot of detonation cord and a shaped charge. You can see the jet as a bright beam. I cannot tell whether the penetration is as good at that range, but shaped charges work over a range of depths.

Bit late, but I haven't been able to find that video(Think it got removed). Still, no shaped charge is that good. They may have used a very large shaped charge to get it, but if so that wouldn't be practical as an actual anti-tank weapon.

It depends on the range and warhead size.
If you want a real world example of this, look up Israel's Trophy system. This essentially did what you are describing, it detonated the projectile before it impacted its target at a safe distance.
Shaped charges retain their shape and velocity for a certain period of time after forming but not indefinitely. It depends on the size of the charge, the geometry of the cone and the material used in order to determine what this timeframe is and what distance it can travel whilst still causing damage. At a certain point the projectile will start to deform and loose velocity due to air resistance which will affect penetration significantly.
There's also a very obvious way to circumvent this system, instead of an explosively shaped projectile, you could simply use a sabot with a tungsten/DPU projectile in front of an explosive charge. So when the warhead detonates due to the force field, the solid kinetic projectile is fired at near hypersonic speeds at the target.
Whilst I can't find an example of this concept actually being used in the real world, the same principle applied to the early AIM-9 missiles which used an explosive charge surrounded by a wire mesh. This allowed the missile to detonate fairly far away from the target as the wire mesh would expand outwards in a ring at supersonic speeds.
As far as lethality is concerned, the LOSAT program proved solid kinetic projectiles can still be lethal when used against relatively modern armor, and that was only Mach 4 with a steel projectile. If an explosive with a high detonation velocity was used, you could possibly reach hypersonic velocities.
This is what a hypersonic kinetic projectile looks like against armor:


I agree that sabots are the best way to beat most current ADSs, but A hybrid approach is not great.  You should either use HEAT or Sabot.  Sabots get a lot of their penetration based on what angle they strike at, but a shell exploding mid-air is likely to send the sabot tumbling, and the extra weight will limit your range and accuracy by just moving some of your propellant from your bullet to your slug.

@Nosajimiki Well I was going off of OPs requirements, they said the "forcefield" was roughly a meter away from the vehicle, I'd be surprised if the sabot deviated significantly off course in that distance/timespan to such an extent that it's ability to penetrate armor is impeded. And I was sort of imaging this as a missile because of the last line in OPs question and not a shell.

Shaped charges only work properly when activated by its detonator
A shaped charges assumes that an explosion will start in one spot, and propagate through the explosive medium in a given way to create the jet that focuses its damage.  Typically the explosion starts in the back and propagates forward.  If you instead have an energy shield that burns a hole in the front or side of the shell, the detonation will start in the wrong spot and be mostly focused out through the hole you just made. This will cause most of the explosive force to shoot the shell backwards or aside or simply to tear itself apart from its wreaked integrity.  If a penetration jet does form at all it will be drastically weakened and less focused.
This effect has already been field proven for over 10 years by the American Iron Curtain and Israeli Trophy APSs which can safely detonate HEAT rounds within a range of 1 meter... so you shield just needs to do the same thing, but with a high energy laser or similar technology.
As For:

premature detonation might even improve penetrative performance

This will typically not improve a modern HEAT round's penetration. Each HEAT round is designed to begin detonation at an optimal range for penetration.  With lower grade High Explosives, this may mean a longer contact fuse, but if it detonates at any point other than when the contact fuse is designed to make contact, it will lose some of its performance.
There may be exceptions with a few older styles of RPGs, but TOW missiles and later will generally have optimized triggers.
What can happen though is a premature detonation could increase its area of effect.  If you have some unarmored assets like infantry and a shield detonates the HEAT round prematurely, it could cause the HEAT shell to explode in a less directed, more spread out fashion which could increase the total damage or casualties.
If you want it to work more like slat armor
So this is less realistic, but what if your shields were meant to actually disable a HEAT round like slat armor instead of just blasting it.  For this your shield would need to be able to apply some manner of crushing effect on shell without allowing the fuse to form a circuit.  Slat armor works by allowing the shell's contact fuse to (sometimes) pass between the slats so that they can crush or slice the shell before it detonates.  This will in some cases short circuit the trigger mechanism and in others just deform the round enough that it explodes instead of forming a proper jet.
This kind of shielding would require a less scientifically realistic system, but if the shield were somehow able to implode the shell or create an electrically insulating non-conductive kinetic barrier it could potentially disable the fuse without detonating the shell at all.

Yes
This would actually be a very effective method of blocking shaped charges. Shaped charges work, in short, by creating a short-range jet that penetrates the armor. While that jet can make its way through a lot of armor, it is short-ranged in nature. Thus, if you can make the shaped charge detonate far enough away from the armor, it would render it completely useless. No shaped charge can still penetrate decent armor when detonated a meter away, so it would render the shaped charge totally useless. This was actually a tactic employed by the Filipino military, except they stuck wood onto their vehicles to detonate the warheads early(this was against obsolete RPGs which detonated on contact, and wouldn't fool modern-shaped charges). This is the same principle

TL;DR Yes, if shaped charges magically detonated a meter away it would be harmless to a tank.

Except that shaped charges actually need to detonate before they are physically in contact with the armour. The correct stand-off detonation distance varies between warheads - it's why there's a long, thin nose with a contact fuse on the front of the old 84mm Carl Gustav round to make it detonate before the main body is in contact with the armour it is impacting.  It's also why top-attack submunitions are designed to detonate above, not on, the top of a tank. TL;DR - it depends on lots of factors, but a metre or so may not help, though tens of metres with a chain-link fence may help.

@KerrAvon2055 Not exactly.  They need time for the detonation to propagate; so, yes, they start thier detonation before contact, but they don't "finish" exploding until they close to contact range.  If you begin the detonation of any given HEAT round before or after its contact fuse is supposed to make contact, then thier effectiveness is drastically reduced.  That delay is precisely calculated based on what explosive and projectile velocity you are using. Actual APSs can effectively detonate HEAT rounds within ~1 meter.

Reading more about this, I don't think the wood worked because it detonated the RPGs earlly.  It worked because the RPGs had electrical fuses that would only trigger on contact with metal.  When they hit the wood, the fuse would be crushed without triggering; so, by the time they penetrated to the metal armor underneath, the fuse was already ruined.
